# Python Web Server and File Download

Tags: python

I've made [this simple HTTP server in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html):

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

What I want to do now, but I don't know how, is the following:

When I visit `http://localhost:8000/my/path/download?documentID=100` , a document (particularly a PDF file) will start being downloaded automatically. Of course, I have more documents but I want them to be identified by the get paramater `documentID`

What is the easiest way to achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a new handle. http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php shows a simple example.

You have to:

- determinate the PDF-File out of the ID
- read the pdf file
- send the right content-flag
- send the pdf file

alternative:

- write a script saving the pdfs with the ids like 1.pdf, 2.pdf
- use your example code
- and simple use links like `http://localhost:8000/my/path/1.pdf`

Greets Kuishi

PS: English isn't my native language, sorry

Comment: yes, t hat's a good point to make my own handler. But from what Ive been searching so far it seems that splitting the path is the only way to find out my get params. maybe I'm wrong

Comment: the alterntive is not uk. I want to start download the file, not to open it in the browser

Comment: Open in browser or downloading is a decision of the client (the browser). There are techniques to force a download but I think its bad design to force that. The users are still able to right click and "save as...". BTW. Im not sure how safe this python simple http server is for productive usage.

Comment: I am not using it for production. I am simply trying to immitate the action of another server. When I visit a certain URL like the above mentioned, I get ask if I want to save the file or open it.